# How do you create a BMVC (TwitterBootstrapMVC) link with image?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to do this using BMVC (a.k.a. TwitterBootstrapMVC5)?

Example Razor page below:

```
@{
    var alt = "microsoft homepage";    
    var url = "http://www.microsoft.com/";
    var logo = "~/Content/Images/microsoft_logo.png";
}

<!-- The old school way works just fine; also not using any variables -->
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/">
    <img alt="microsoft homepage" src="~/Content/Images/microsoft_logo.png" />
</a>

<!-- This does not work using BMVC (the link works but fails at rendering the logo and has no alternate text) -->
@Html.Bootstrap().Link(@logo, @url)
```

In other words, is there a *"short and sweet"* way to create a link (with image) using BMVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gee wiz, this was a pretty simple solution once I took another look at it.

```
@{
    // Note, the necessary absence of the "~" tilde in the src attribute below.
    var img = "<img alt='microsoft homepage' src='/Content/Images/microsoft_logo.png'/>";
    var url = "http://www.microsoft.com/";
}

<!-- The simple solution! -->    
@Html.Bootstrap().Link(@img, @url)
```

On a side note, wouldn't it be nice if BMCV had a built-in ImageLink and ImageActionLink?

Comment: Yes it would; make a pull request! However http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/09/asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-2-preview-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx makes me think that BMVC will eventually be moot. See bootstrap HTML helpers built into MVC 5.1

Comment: TwitterBootstrapMVC5 (BMVC) is no longer free. https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Download But what I just saw from Microsoft's MVC 5.1 is still a far cry from what this library can do for you. Either way, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Oh yes, I've been following it for some time now - it's technically free for bootstrap 2, but not bootstrap 3. Obviously, why not use 3? :) It's a pretty reasonably priced license imo. Maybe HTML Helpers will advance to use Bootstrap more, would be neat. Heck, Dmitri could even sell it to MSFT.

Comment: I think he'd get the same price as Tim McCall got for AttributeRouting. A pat on the back???

Answer (score 1):

https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation#buttons-link
Enh?

I realize it's just a link, but the documentation should be sufficient

Basic Usage

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Link("awesome website", "http://www.website.net")
```

Html output

```
<a href="http://www.website.net">awesome website</a>
```

I think I missed something. You want an  there, don't you?

Maybe

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Link("<img src=\"@logo\"/>", "http://www.website.net")
```

?

Comment: The documentation nor examples use an image.

Comment: Although your solution did not work it helped me come to the eventual solution - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), or another icon library, then you can do this sort of thing:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Link("<span class='icon fa fa-globe'></span> Globe", url)
```